# Using IO () operations, but returning IO X

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I have a function which returns IO X (assume X is a specific type). One of its arguments is a path to an output directory. If this doesn't exists, it has to be created.

I wanted to use createDirectoryIfMissing which returns IO (), but I don't know how to keep the types consistent. What I did (and failed) was something like this:

```
process :: (Mutation a, Show a, Arbitrary a)
=> ((a -> BSL.ByteString),(BS.ByteString -> a))
-> Bool -> FilePath -> String -> String ->
Int -> Int -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO Result 
process (mencode,mdecode) par filename cmd prop maxSuccess maxSize outdir seeds =  
let (prog, args) = (Prelude.head spl, Prelude.tail spl)
in (case prop of
    "exec" ->
        quickCheckWithResult stdArgs { maxSuccess = maxSuccess , maxSize = maxSize, chatty = not par }
        (noShrinking $ execprop filename prog args mencode outdir)
    "honggfuzz" ->
        --do
        --createDirectoryIfMissing True outdir (This fails)
        quickCheckWithResult stdArgs { maxSuccess = maxSuccess , maxSize = maxSize, chatty = not par }
        (noShrinking $ honggprop filename prog args mencode outdir)

    _     -> process_custom arbitrary (mencode,mdecode) par filename cmd prop maxSuccess maxSize outdir seeds

) where spl = splitOn " " cmd
```

quickCheckWithResult :: Testable prop => Args -> prop -> IO Result
process_custom is basically the same as process, but with another parameter

EDIT: actual code now, sorry

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Please at least give type signatures for the things you use that compile successfully, and full code of the bit you're stuck on.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. You want to create a directory and return something particular after that?

Comment: why are people trying to obfuscate their code - you are learning and probably not producing the most beautiful code out there - that's fine - give us your worst we can handle - at least please give a full example showing your problem (including the errors you get) - as soon as I see a `...` I can already tell that the question is probably unanswerable

Comment: this is a great example as the snippet you've shown should actually work and so the problem **is** most likely somewhere in the `...` black boxes

Comment: Sorry guys, now it has actual code.

Comment: We need type signatures for that other stuff you use!

Comment: The indentation looks a bit suspect. In fact, the lack of indentation in the type signature should prevent it from compiling right away with a syntax error, but I imagine that is a mistake in copying it over. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Well, I was going to write what error message I was getting, but I wrote the code again and now it works. I think it was an indentation problem.
I'm sorry for any trouble I caused.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
foo :: Int -> IO Int
foo n = do
   putStrLn "Hello"   -- :: IO ()
   return (n+1)       -- :: IO Int
```

The last statement in the `do` block has to match with the function signature.

Alternatively, use `>>` or `>>=`:

```
foo n = putStrLn "Hello" >> return (n+1)
bar n = getChar >>= \c -> return (fromEnum c)
```

both have type `Int -> IO Int`.